# Obtaining information about other processes on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, process

How can I get information about other (unrelated to perl.exe) processes in Windows?

Say, I have a script that would like to monitor some basic information about all `firefox.exe` processes.

I would like to do something like:

```
#!perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use MagicModule qw/ read_process_info /;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ps = MagicModule::read_process_info();

print Dumper($ps);
```

and see something like:

```
$VAR = [
    {
        ProcessName  => 'firefox.exe',
        PID          => 1234,
        PirvateBytes => 21153546,
        WorkingSet   => 134566354,
        # etc...
    },
    {
        ProcessName  => 'firefox.exe',
        PID          => 1556,
        PirvateBytes => 15435487,
        WorkingSet   => 245774448,
        # etc...
    },
    {
        ProcessName  => 'calc.exe',
        PID          => 2777,
        PirvateBytes => 1024,
        WorkingSet   => 4096,
        # etc...
    },
];
```

For I was obtaining this info by parsing output from Systinternals' PsExec, but obviously this is not efficient at all.

What are some nice Perl ways to obtain this data?

(Solution working with Strawberry Perl on Windows XP—Windows 7 would be preferred.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WMI using [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE) is one of the easiest ways I've seen:

```
use Win32::OLE qw<in>;
use constant wbemFlagReturnImmediately => 0x10;
use constant wbemFlagForwardOnly => 0x20;

my $objWMIService 
    = Win32::OLE->GetObject( 'winmgmts:\\\\localhost\root\CIMV2' ) 
    or die 'WMI connection failed.\n'
    ;

my @processes  
    = in $objWMIService->ExecQuery( 
      'SELECT * FROM Win32_Process'
    , 'WQL'
    ,  wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly
    );
```

And then you can consult the object definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Keep in mind that each field can be accessed like a hash key or a method name: ( `$_->{Caption}` or `$_->Caption` )

Comment: I have put this into life and it works like a charm -> accepting :)